Question for Software Developers in Rural Areas
Location:  United States
I need some advice from software developers in the United States, who work in rural areas.  How feasible is it to obtain sufficient internet access, for the type of work you do?  Do you have any advice for identifying whether a home has sufficient internet access, before buying a home in a rural area?
I am a software engineer, looking to buy a home in the countryside.  I am hoping to purchase a property with at least 4 acres of land.  The location would be about 20-30 miles outside of a major city.  There are areas of the country where internet access is not sufficient for telework.  I do not want to make an investment in a new home, only to find out that I cannot support my career based on that location.  I would need download speeds of 500 Mbps.
I have checked feedback online about internet access, and there are varying responses, usually from folks who do not work in computer science, so they may be unaware of the speed and reliability that is needed.  I have also found a government website from the FCC, https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/home, which lists what access is available by address.  I wonder if folks have used this website and whether they find it reliable?
Any advice about determining whether a rural location might have sufficient internet access would be much appreciated.

It really does depend on what you do - I do db work, and need both download and upload speeds.  I tried satellite, and the ping (with vpn) was so slow it didn't work, although the download speeds were great.  Cable isn't available, but fiber has finally shown up, and that will work.

Why do you need 500 mbs? I have survived at < 3 mbs for most of my life. Life hack, you can upload/download stuff while you sleep/aren't looking at your computer screen.

"I would need download speeds of 500 Mbps." is a patently absurd claim. The only limiting factor where internet performance matters is (a) reasonable browsing speeds and (b) an upload rate equivalent to how many changes you are making to your codebase. Neither of these come even close to needing 500mbps.

Depending on the mobile carrier you choose, you only need to be within 25 miles of the tower to get sufficient bandwidth. Most places within 100 miles of a major city have sufficient mobile data service.

I am not in the US, but here in some EU countries, we have unlimited mobilnet packages with very acceptable bandwidth for about $30/month. If you want to make sure, you can make 2 contracts and you are fine.

@DavidR Only problem is that face-to-face videochat needs high and trustable bandwidth.

@GraySheep Trustable bandwidth is dependent on the landscape. You simply need a clear line of sight to the tower. If the place you are looking at is in a valley with a hill between that place and the tower, you won't have good communication. Apart from that, all forms of bandwidth in a rural area will have events which disrupt it, neighbors who congest the line, and other problems.

Developer here, with a 150mbps connection: Not having an issue at all. Only large downloads obviously, but there is a rare occurence, at least for me. It is stable though, that is important

It really depends on exactly which rural area you are talking about, and which address within that rural area. I would suggest asking the town which broadband providers are available in general, then contacting each and asking them if they would serve your address and with what bandwidth.
Ditto for cellular telephone service, if you were thinking about getting network access that way.
(The US is a big place, with fewer federalized services than many countries. General answers are generally difficult to give good answers to. Unfortunately there's a trade-off between being specific enough to be answerable and being too specific for Stack Exchange, so focusing on how to get the answer rather than on the answer itself if often a good strategy.)

The only way to really know.  I live between two major cities(50miles to one, 65 to the other), very much suburban, not rural, 2GB download speed available through cable.  I grew up 75 miles from a minor city(60K population), very rural, but they currently have 1GB download speed available through cable,

Not in the US, but am in NZ - and we have our Rural areas too
I am going to link to a thread that discusses something that may or may not be relevant: here - A not uncommon scenario in NZ is that Fibre by Chorus (the company that took over the Infrastructure of our state owned Telco) will be laid past an area, but a home might be 200-300 metres away from it - some Farmers have tractors and trenching tools and will either run their own Fibre or do some of the work themselves.
In some instances, a group of houses have clubbed together to pay for the laying of Fibre ($80K split between say 4 neighbours) as once the cable is laid, other people can leverage it.
I am presuming in the US that companies will do something similar - e.g. if you are willing to pay for it, they will do it.
The question is a matter of cost. It is not cheap to lay the Cable. Once it is laid, it is relatively cheap - but that up-front cost is large.


I do not want to make an investment in a new home

Ask the people you're potentially buying from for the information. You cannot be sure any other way, and also make sure there are no outstanding bills associated with it. You can move to a place with a cable and find it's turned off until the outstanding is paid.
Connectivity is critical to me, I'm not in the USA, but when I go anywhere I ask the right questions from the specific people who will know. And then I doublecheck on them.

I would go further and ask that something like Speedtest get run.  Maybe even bring a laptop and run it during a house tour, if the speed is that critical.

Yep, that's what I meant by 'doublecheck'


I am a software engineer, looking to buy a home in the countryside. I
am hoping to purchase a property with at least 4 acres of land. The
location would be about 20-30 miles outside of a major city.

In many parts of the United States this means you will be looking in the first set of counties around the city. They have urban areas and areas where the minimum lot size is 3,5, or even 10 acres. You may have to go 1 or 2 more counties away before you would be considered rural.

There are areas of the country where internet access is not sufficient
for telework. I do not want to make an investment in a new home, only
to find out that I cannot support my career based on that location. I
would need download speeds of 500 Mbps.

You may find that most counties/towns/cities near these major cities have a contract with a cable company to provide services. In addition the main telephone company will also provide internet access. The major companies should have a tool that will check what services are available at your address. That will also allow you to see the maximum speed they will guarantee they can provide to that address.
I did look at the federal website you linked to. It seems reasonable for the few addresses I checked in both urban and rural areas. Because there is required infrastructure for these non-satellite systems, the local government can require service level agreements regarding speed, latency, and reliability.

I have checked feedback online about internet access, and there are
varying responses, usually from folks who do not work in computer
science, so they may be unaware of the speed and reliability that is
needed.

In many families the minimum amount of bandwidth they will need is 100 Mbps, with many needing 500 Mbps. If you are needing to upload more data your greater need is the upload speed. In other cases latency will be the most important factor.
You should also check with your employer. Some companies will reimburse some teleworkers for their above average network requirements.
Note: If when you said buy you meant build, then the developer/builder will have to tell you what infrastructure they plan on linking to and at what cost.

Many times a service provider in the US will say the address is served by a service but in reality they will come back asking for very pricey charges to hook up the service. I would not trust their providers website. I would suggest making it the sellers problem to solve.

@Donald And then the seller will sell to someone else. There are a lot more homebuyers on the market then there are homes to buy.

@Questor - That isn’t the case in the US or many parts of the country

@Donald I can only tell you what I pay for, and what I get. I have no idea if that will meet the needs of the buyer. If they don't believe the government website, the county government and the provider there is no solution.

@Donald I was speaking for the US. There is currently a 4 month stock of houses on the market. It is still a sellers market. It won't be a buyers market until that number hits about 7 months... The average time on the market for a house is 60 days.

@mhoran_psprep - What government website? If we’re talking about wireless coverage that data is supplied by the providers in the US and I can promise that data is partially incorrect. There is no federal government provided internet in the US, and local government provided services, varies from state to state.

I am not in the US, but one of your neighbours in Canada, living on some acres where no internet service providers have wired connections. I was able to remote work 100% on a satellite service running only 25Mbps with a 200GB data cap/75ms ping for a couple of years, before Starlink come along giving me 250Mbps with unlimited data which is excellent.
What you learn to do is tweak your working processes to take into account the data you need and where you need it. I keep a machine at the office, and remote desktop to that through VPN, if I need heavy data transactions. If I want to work tomorrow at home with this data, I download it at night whilst sleeping, which is rare.
A lot of coding, in my case, can be done locally, after a one-time large GitHub transfer.
Remote desktop and VNC, I configure them to low bandwidth, so they compress the screens full colour transfers to compressed low color transfers. This would changes a remote which scans down the screen to an instantly updating lower quality image.
As long as your company has a decent VPN and you can get something 50Mbps+ then remote is completely possible.
There are a few thing about moving remote. Power outages during extreme weather can be an issue. I tether through my cell + laptop and RDP to the office machine when this happens.
The commute when you are forced to go into the office for something.
If you are not able to get something like Starlink with unlimited data, and you have a large family watching the movies and scrolling the memes, then you could run into annoying instances where family usage puts you to the data cap and you drop speed. This used to happen to me in the early days and in the end I got a second service dedicated to myself, so I did not have to police the internet day and night. Part of the moving rural discussion with the family should include a discussion of reasonable internet use.
It will cost you much more, but the lifestyle is worth it. Nothing quite like taking the laptop to the patio, overlooking trees with no neighbours and doing some coding., so
